# Best control to be used as dropdown list in android

Tags: android, android-widget

I have an activity which one of its components is a EditText. The goal of it is the following: when user clicks/taps on it, another activity is called to select some items (categories). I have implemented it using an activity that extends listactivity and using a custom adapter to paint custom rows for items.

All is ok, but I guess if using a EditText is the best option. The problem using this kind of control is that when user clicks/taps on it, the virtual keyboard appears and I do not want it to appear. If I use a TextView instead, virtual keyboard does not appear, but it is not clear for user that he have to click/tap on it to select a category (as the underscore line is not shown here as when using EditText).

So what android widget is the best to use in this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always use expandable list view there are many examples online that could help u to create it much more flexible than a spinner and it looks elegant and easy to use, it also show the user directly what is used for by just giving it a look and u can always customize it and play with its look and functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking for a [`Spinner`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/spinner.html)? That way you wouldn't have to load up a separate Activity to make the category selection. Otherwise, why not just use a Button? It's obviously clickable, that's for sure!

Comment: Yes, but I don't like to use an spinner... I think it is not as customizable as a listview.

Comment: You can customize the dropdown and selected row layouts independently (see the [`getDropDownView`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getDropDownView(int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup)) method on `ArrayAdapter`).

Comment: I am  new in android development sorry.... but would it be possible to use an spinner and on click to show my activity screen?

Comment: It would be *possible*, but the idea behind my suggestion to use the Spinner is that the second Activity may become redundant in that case. The user could select an option from the Spinner's drop-down in the first Activity, without needing to separately navigate to a second Activity. If keeping the second Activity is important, then a Spinner would not make much sense. In that case, I would fall back to using a Button. After all, a button is the most obviously-clickable widget available to us.

Comment: Finally I have used an edittext and I have set its focusable property to false. Also I have set a default text that says "tap here to select". So now user knows that it can modify it and once it clicks on, no virtual keyboard is shown and my activity implementing listactivity is shown. Personally, spinner is more suitable to present user a few options but not when you have to presents a lot of options to select. Also I think, with an activity implementing listactivity or even expandable as Ahmad said, is more customizable and powerful.